# How do i animate the send icon when i hover on the button

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, css-animations

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button [disabled]="btnStatus" class="btn btn-secondary buttonSend" type="submit">
        <div [hidden]="btnStatus">
          Send Message&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: -6px;">send</i>
        </div>

        <div [hidden]="!btnStatus" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-light" role="status">
           <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
       </div>
          
    </button>
</div>
```

In the above HTML code i want to animate the send icon such that it translates on X axix when i hover on the button.

I have tried

```
.buttonSend:hover .buttonIcon
{
    animation: logoAnim 0.5s forwards;
}


@keyframes logoAnim 
{
   from 
   {
     transform: translateX(0);
   }
   to
   {
     transform: translateX(10);
     opacity: 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove `.buttonIcon` from `.buttonSend:hover .buttonIcon {...}` as there is no element with that class name.

```css
.buttonSend:hover {
  animation: logoAnim 0.5s forwards;
}
```

Now, fix the typo where you set the button to translate 10px to the right which is written **10** without mentioning the units which are in pixels **px**

```css
@keyframes logoAnim  {
   from {
     transform: translateX(0);
   }

   to {
     transform: translateX(10px);
     opacity: 0;
   }
}
```

---

Complete code:

```css
.buttonSend:hover {
  animation: logoAnim 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes logoAnim {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    /* mention the units (px)! */
    transform: translateX(10px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <button [disabled]="btnStatus" class="btn btn-secondary buttonSend" type="submit">
        <div [hidden]="btnStatus">
          Send Message&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: -6px;">send</i>
        </div>

        <div [hidden]="!btnStatus" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-light" role="status">
           <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
       </div>
          
    </button>
</div>
```